# What layout manager should I use

Tags: java, swing, awt, chat

I am making a chat in java and need to display old messages in a JPanel. I need an image and the message that was being sent/received to be displayed, each on its own row. The code that I currently have :

```
JFrame f = new JFrame();
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

JPanel container = new JPanel();
container.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 400));

// Printing five messages
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    JPanel p = new JPanel();
    p.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 40));
    p.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
    p.setLayout(new BoxLayout(p, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

    JLabel img = new JLabel("Image : ");
    JLabel txt = new JLabel("This is some text");

    p.add(img);
    p.add(txt);

    img.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    txt.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);

    container.add(p);
}

f.add(container);
f.pack();
f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
f.setVisible(true);
```

Result :
[image]

Right now I am specifying the width and height of each message which is not so good as it should automatically resize to its content. I feel like there should be a good layout-manager for this but I am new to swing so help is appreciated as I do not know which one to use.

Comment: You could use a `GridLayout(0, 1)` (variable number of rows, one column), but myself, I'd probably display that as a JList with a custom renderer, one that showed an image and text. Either that or a JTable with two columns: image and text

Comment: I would use a JEditorPane myself, but your requirement might be different.  Also many Swing components will interpret simple HTML if you tell them to, so `"<html><p><image/>Some text.</p>"` isn't out of the question too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it should automatically resize to its content.

Having text that wraps to a new line is the main problem here.

One way might be to:

1. use vertical Box - it allows each component to have a different height
2. wrap the text in HTML - it will allow for the text to wrap

Something like:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Chat extends JPanel
{
    private Box messageBox = Box.createVerticalBox();

    public Chat()
    {
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
        add(messageBox, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        addMessage("Short message");
        addMessage("A longer message that should wrap as reqired onto another line. This should happen dynamically");
    }

    public void addMessage(String text)
    {
        JPanel messagePanel = new JPanel( new BorderLayout() );

        JLabel label = new JLabel( new ImageIcon("about16.gif") );
        messagePanel.add(label, BorderLayout.LINE_START);

        JLabel message = new JLabel("<html>" + text + "</html>");
        messagePanel.add(message);

        messageBox.add(messagePanel);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Chat");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new Chat());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(200, 100);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> createAndShowGUI() );
    }
}
```